# Difference between std::decay and std::remove_reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++20

When template metaprogramming in C++, I often run into something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
S<T> make_wrapper(T&& t) { return S<T>(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

I know I should use something like `std::decay` in the return type, but why wouldn't `std::remove_reference` work as well? What's the difference here? What about `std::remove_cvref`?

Comment: [decay can do a lot more](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) depending on what `T` is.

Comment: Have you tried to read about them? For example [this `std::decay` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) and [this `std::remove_reference` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74257533/difference-between-stddecay-and-stdremove-cvref

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Removing reference would leave `const` and `volatile`.  If that is what you want, then it will suffice.

Removing cvref does most of what decay does, but doesn't convert function types and array types to pointers.

decay converts a type in a way that you could reasonably store a copy of it in an array or in a `struct`, or return it from or pass it to a function.

In this specific case:

```
template <typename T>
S<T> make_wrapper(T&& t) { return S<T>(std::forward<T>(t)); }
```

this looks like you are using universal references, and you don't intend users to pass in a specific type `T`.

If they pass in a `const T`, odds are you don't want to produce a `S<T const>` but rather a `S<T>`.

Removing references, then removing const-volatile, is probably a good idea here.  `std::decay` does both.  It *also* converts arrays into pointers and functions into pointers-to-functions, which makes something like:

```
template<class T>
struct S {
  T t;
  T copy() const { return t; }
};
```

compile.  Functions can't be stored, and arrays can't be returned from functions (or taken as function arguments really), which makes them strange types; `std::decay` does this transformation for you.

OTOH, that transformation might be surprising.

Answer (score 20):

Consider for example

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<
        std::decay_t<const int&>, 
        std::remove_reference_t<const int&>
    >); // int != const int
}
```

`std::decay` will remove any cv-qualifer, `remove_reference` won't. It will just strip the "reference" part of the type.

From the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

> Applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer
>   implicit conversions to the type T, removes cv-qualifiers, and defines
>   the resulting type as the member typedef type.

Therefore `std::decay` will perform way more type conversions than `std::remove_reference`.

There are also further type modifiers for more nuanced applications that will only perform selected parts of the set of possible transformations `decay` does, like `remove_cv`, `remove_volatile` or, in C++20, `remove_cvref`.

Comment: Is `std::remove_cvref` enough?

Comment: @Nex': No. It really only takes 2 minutes to read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay).

Comment: @Nex' Maybe you also should consider the use of `std::invoke`.