# Use of std::forward with Eigen::Ref objects

Tags: c++, templates, reference, eigen, c++20

I have a functor `Foo` defined as follows:

```
struct Foo {
    template <typename _Vector>
    void operator()(const Eigen::Ref<const _Vector>&, const Eigen::Ref<const _Vector>&) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

I'd like to call it with either Eigen vectors, blocks, or Eigen::Ref, and `_Vector` can be any of Eigen vector types. This implementation doesn't work because you must call it *exactly* with `Eigen::Ref<const _Vector>` arguments -- and not, for instance, with vectors, or segments of vectors. A workaround I found is the following:

```
struct Foo {
    /* This works, but I'm not sure if it is the most correct solution. */
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void operator()(const T& x, const U& y) {
        Impl<typename T::PlainObject>(x, y);
    }

    /* This doesn't work, but I expected this to be the most correct solution. */
    // template <typename T, typename U>
    // void operator()(T&& x, U&& y) {
    //     Impl<typename T::PlainObject>(std::forward<T>(x), std::forward<U>(y));
    // }

    template <typename _Vector>
    void Impl(const Eigen::Ref<const _Vector>&, const Eigen::Ref<const _Vector>&) {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Here, I hide the implementation inside a function `Impl` and catch every argument with `operator()`; then, I deduce the right `_Vector` type from the member type `PlainObject` of the first argument (`x`). However, I expect the commented code to be more "correct" since it perfectly forwards the arguments, so that they are used by `Impl` being exactly as they were supposed to be. **Is this assertion wrong?** Unfortunately, it fails with the following error:

```
error: ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >&’ is not a class, struct, or union type
[build]   390 |         Impl<typename T::PlainObject>(std::forward<T>(x), std::forward<U>(y));
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It states that `Eigen::Ref` is not a class, struct, or union type; but it actually is a class. **How can this error be solved?**

P.S.: I must confess that I'm not 100% confident I understood when `T&&` and `std::forward` should be used. My understanding is that they give you exactly what you pass with no extra copies or implicit conversions.

Comment: Does `T` have a typedef named `PlainObject`? What is `Impl`? Can you make it into a [mre]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the code I provided is already minimal and works as long as you have access to the Eigen libraries. `PlainObject` is a member type defined for all Eigen types and defines the underlying type of any Eigen object, whether it be a block, segment, Eigen::Ref, etc.

Comment: Ok, if that's there I hope what I put in the answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> error: ‘Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >&’ is not a class, struct, or union type
>                                                  ^
> ```

You need to [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to make the version with perfect forwarding valid:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
void operator()(T&& x, U&& y) {
     Impl<typename std::remove_reference_t<T>::PlainObject>(std::forward<T>(x),
                                                            std::forward<U>(y));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works! Maybe, `std::decay_t` could be an even better option, right? Also, could you kindly answer the first question in bold font, i.e., **is the solution with rvalue references the "correct" one?**

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you may want `decay` under certain circumstances: [Difference between `std::decay` and `std::remove_reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872454/7582247). I don't think it matters here though. Both versions are "correct" but this one is probably preferable since it allows for perfect forwarding.