# Difference between std::decay and std::remove_cvref?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Does `std::remove_cvref` replace `std::decay` after C++20?

From [this link](https://github.com/thecppzoo/zoo/issues/7),
I cannot understand what this means:

> C++20 will have a new trait `std::remove_cvref` that doesn't have undesirable effect of `std::decay` on arrays

What is the undesirable effect of `std::decay`?

Example and explanation, please!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::remove_cvref` does not replace `std::decay`. They are used for two different things.

An array naturally decays into a pointer to its first element. `std::decay` will decay an array type to a pointer type. So, for example, `std::decay<const char[N]>::type` is `const char*`.

Whereas `std::remove_cvref` removes `const`, `volatile` and `&` from a type without changing anything else about the type. So, for example, `std::remove_cvref<const char[N]>::type` is `char[N]` rather than `char*`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 8):

For non-array and non-function types [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) and [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) are the same. However, for function and array types `std::decay` behaves differently:

- It doesn't remove CV or reference qualifiers
- For arrays it decays (the first dimension)to a pointer
- For function types, it converts them to function pointers

Read more on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: I appreciate your answer!